# How to create a set of rows from a number in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select statement with the following result table

```
name count
A    2
B    1
C    3
D    2
```

The numbers are a result of a count operation. What I want is:

```
name number
A    1
A    2
B    1
C    1
C    2
C    3
D    1
D    2
```

The result table should have the numbers from 1 to the count number.
How can this be done with SQL(-function) or temporary table or any other way?

Comment: there's no easy way in mysql to convert single records into multiple records.you'd have to write a sproc for this, or just expand the rows in client-side code.

Comment: When you say the result of a count operation, do you mean another query returns the grouped counts?  If so, show that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get an enumerated list of integers.  If your table is big enough, you can use that:

```
select t.name, n.n
from (select @rn := @rn + 1 as n
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) vars
     ) n join
     t
     on n.n <= t.count;
```

Comment: Could you explain this, I'm not that SQL guru to understand this. What do you mean with 'if your table is big enough'? I have added the original query to my question.

Comment: got it! Just removed the 'table' in 'from table' and it works under MySQL.

Comment: @BeJotEl . . . I mean that the number of rows in the table is sufficient for all the counts.  So, if the maximum of `count` is 50, then there are at least 50 rows in the table.